# What is the best position of placing a cart icon in Ecommerce websites?

Tags: user-expectation, e-commerce, shopping-cart

I told to design an eCom websites using all new UX. Not the old ones what so many companies or websites using.

When we surf the eCom we see a Cart Icon mostly in left corner. I want to change the placing of that icon.

After some research I found to fix it as sticky button over the left side of the screen and suppose when **user wants to Add something into the cart, he just have to long press the product, Drawer will open from the left and he just have to drag the product into it.** After that the details of that product will appear in the drawer.

User anytime can access to his cart by clicking on that sticky button over the left. And when User scrolls  scrolls, the sticky button will also scrolls. 
he can delete, manage the quntities and check out from the drawer itself.

Guys, please let me know is this is a good UX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*From your description, I assume you are focused on mobile.*

#### Cart indicator & navigation

In my experience, regardless of what the latest hotness may be, a sticky header with a cart button in the upper right wins every time. Mobile or desktop, it just works.

#### Adding to the cart

As for adding to the cart, I find the long-press then drag interaction annoying for a few reasons.

1. I have to learn that you want me to do that.
2. It assumes that I'd want to add to cart from a browsing page with no further details.
3. It's slow and requires some degree of precision.

I'd stick with a good ol' add to cart button that's high on the product detail page. Just a scroll away users will find all the info they need to make the purchase decision.

Comment: There will be Add to cart button in product details page, User can drag the item from the homepage's featured product if they know the description of the product.

Comment: That's a lot to develop for something that **1** isn't obvious to the user and **2** isn't a very common scenario. You're addressing a small fraction of a small fraction.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a nice interaction, but I would like to warm you that **users are not at all used to such a pattern anywhere**.

And changing a pattern just for the sake of being modern will **cost you in sales.**

And if still they force you to incorporate the new interaction, **make sure you provide a tutorial/walk-through of sorts**, so that users can learn this pattern

And its always good to **test your interaction with users**. You'll get amazing insights.

Comment: testing will be done. Thank you. Do you have any more inputs?

Comment: na, that should do. All the best.